# How to get specific sized image on extension app in iOS 8?

Tags: ios

I want to get image which has specific size(width=300, height=200) on extension app

How to use option? 
https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSItemProvider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSItemProvider/loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler:

options: 
A dictionary of keys and values that provide information about the item, such as the size of an image. (See NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey for a key you can use.)

```
for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
        if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                 if(image) {
                     [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                         self.imageView.image = image;
                     }];
                 }
             }];
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: jeffamaphone, Thanks quick reply. But I want to know how use NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey

Comment: `FOUNDATION_EXTERN NSString * const NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0); // NSValue of CGSize or NSSize, specifies image size in pixels.`
this is written in source code (not the documentation)
but I couldn't get this working, so jeffamaphone's answer is probably the only solution

Comment: I'm using NSDictionary *itemOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)] forKey:NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey];
                [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:itemOptions completionHandler:^(UIImage *item, NSError *error) { }]; Seems it's not working. Any solution you found?